# An error when loading a 2mb dataset of floating points (python)

Tags: python-3.x

Does any one know why i got an error of "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'bcs.xlsx'" when i'm loading this file of size 2mb it has around 60,000 rows and 4 columns.
i tried using csv instead of xlsx but i get the same error and i've checked hundreds times that the script and the file are at he same directory.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Python does *not* find your file, errors are not lying.

But there's a misunderstanding in your question, you checked that the file is in the same directory as your script, but that's not the check you have to do. You have to check the file is in the current [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) of your python script.

To see your current working directory, use:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

And as we're at it you can list this directory:

```
print(os.listdir())
```

I don't know how you execute your script, but if you're using a terminal emulator, a typical way to give a file name to a program is by argument, not hardcoding its name, like by using [argparse](https://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html). And if you do this way, your shell completion may help you naming your file properly, like:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('file', type=argparse.FileType('r'))
args = parser.parse_args()

print(args.file.read())
```

Now on a shell if you type:

```
python3 ./thescript.py ./th[TAB]
```

your shell will autocomplete "./th" to "./thescript.py" (if and only if it exists), highly reducing the probablity of having a typo. Typically if there's a space in the filename like "the script.py", your shell should properly autocomplete `the\ script.py`.

Also if you use argparse with the `argparse.FileType` as I did, you'll have a verbose error in case the file does not exist:

```
thescript.py: error: argument file: can't open 'foo': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'foo'
```

But… you already have a verbose error.